# Send a Ctrl-C command to a nodeJS process called in python

Tags: python

I have a complicated python script which has this function :

```
def createVehicle():
  i = 0
  while i < 4:
    os.system("./funScript <arguments>")
    i += 1
```

The python script runs a lot of complicated logic, and has this code at the end :

```
tempThread = threading.Thread(name='daemon', target=createVehicle)
tempThread.setDaemon(True)
tempThread.start()
//A lot of other fun stuff
tempThread.join()
```

Now, the shell script funScript is not my creation, and looks like this

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
const vehicle = require("${__dirname}/../src/Vehicle");
//A lot of fun stuff with argument modification
vehicle.runEngine()
```

vehicle.runEngine() runs for around 10 mins.

Currently, after I run this program and use Ctrl-C, what happens is that it terminates runEngine() first. So I need to press Ctrl-C 5 times to actually terminate the whole process.

Is there any way I can terminate this program in 1 Ctrl-C command?